# Sequelize update a belongsToMany relation

Tags: sequelize.js

How do I update a belongsToMany relationship in sequelize.

I want to delete the relationships in the "through" table and I don't know if I'm doing the right approach

```
const [row, [dataRow]] = await Event.update(payload, { where: { id }, returning: true })
await EventsPets.destroy({ where: { EventId: dataRow.id } })
await dataRow.addPets(PetIds)`
```

I basically delete them and then create them again...

What I'm hoping for is that updating will update the relationships without having to delete them and then create them again

Comment: Nadie me ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but I've been needing to do the same thing, and I'll leave here how I solved it.

What you have to do is before (or after) updating, with the update method the table you want to modify, add this (I'm going to work with the Post and Tag tables because you don't specify what the tables you use are called).

```js
// If you want to update a tag inside post:
const post = await Post.findByPk(req.body.id);
if (post .id !== req.body.tagId) { // Check that it is not the same
     post.setTags(req.body.tagId)
   }

// If you want to update a post from a tag:
const tag = await Tag.findByPk(req.body.id);
tag.setPosts(req.body.tagId)
```

Note: It is important to use the plural when doing the "set" method: setPosts, setTags, setEvents, etc. I was missing that that's why it didn't work :)

It is not the same as what I explain here, but I was guided by the solution on this documentation page (https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/associations/belongs-to-many/#association-setter-setx)